# How to override a SVG color coming from backend?

Tags: css, svg

I have links with their own SVGs coming from my backend via my API.

I want to overwrite the color when i'm in dark mode and set it to white.

Here is my component that display the SVG :

```
[...]
<button className="flex items-center fill">
   {value.pictogram &&
      pictogram(value.pictogram, {
            fill: value.pictoFill,
          })}
       {!props.isMinimized && (
          <span className="ml-3">{value.label}</span>
        )}
 </button>
[...]

export const pictogram: any = (key: string, props: any) => {
    return pictogramToComponent[key] ? React.createElement(pictogramToComponent[key], props) : null;
};
```

And the SVG is like this in the DOM :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#C1C1C1"><defs><clipPath id="clip-path-picto-hektor"><rect id="Bold_hyperlink-3" data-name="Bold / hyperlink-3" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(-1862 -1482)" fill="none"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="clip-path-picto-hektor-2"><rect id="Rectangle_2" data-name="Rectangle 2" width="16" height="16" fill="#525254"></rect></clipPath></defs><g id="ico_Hektor" transform="translate(1862 1482)" opacity="0.3" clip-path="url(#clip-path-picto-hektor)"><g id="Groupe_4" data-name="Groupe 4" transform="translate(-1860 -1480)"><g id="Groupe_3" data-name="Groupe 3" transform="translate(0 0)" clip-path="url(#clip-path-picto-hektor-2)"><path id="Trac\xE9_2" data-name="Trac\xE9 2" d="M13.82,1.071Q12.046,0,8.019,0,4.064,0,2.4.961,0,2.289,0,5.8v4.434q0,3.474,2.4,4.8Q4.064,16,8.019,16a11.986,11.986,0,0,0,5.8-1.072Q16,13.635,16,10.235V5.8q0-3.436-2.18-4.73m.964,6.164a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.855,2.889A4.707,4.707,0,0,1,8,8.985a4.707,4.707,0,0,1-2.929,1.139A3.75,3.75,0,0,1,1.216,7.235a.059.059,0,0,1,.107-.049,2.291,2.291,0,0,0,2.022.957A7.284,7.284,0,0,0,6.45,6.8a.548.548,0,0,1,.46-.072L8,7.051l1.09-.319a.548.548,0,0,1,.46.072,7.283,7.283,0,0,0,3.105,1.34,2.292,2.292,0,0,0,2.022-.957.059.059,0,0,1,.106.049" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="#525254"></path></g></g></g></svg>
```

Any idea what should I change to change the color ?

I tried to add `fill` class and do this in my CSS :

```
.fill~svg,
.fill svg,
.fill~path,
.fill path,
.fill~circle,
.fill circle,
.fill~rect,
.fill rect,
.fill~line,
.fill line,
.fill~polyline,
.fill polyline,
.fill~polygon,
.fill polygon,
.fill~text,
.fill text,
.fill~tspan,
.fill tspan,
.fill~g,
.fill g {
  fill: #ffffff !important;
}
```

But nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
svg #ico_Hektor {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
svg path {
  fill: #000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="#C1C1C1"><defs><clipPath id="clip-path-picto-hektor"><rect id="Bold_hyperlink-3" data-name="Bold / hyperlink-3" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(-1862 -1482)" fill="none"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="clip-path-picto-hektor-2"><rect id="Rectangle_2" data-name="Rectangle 2" width="16" height="16" fill="#525254"></rect></clipPath></defs><g id="ico_Hektor" transform="translate(1862 1482)" opacity="0.3" clip-path="url(#clip-path-picto-hektor)"><g id="Groupe_4" data-name="Groupe 4" transform="translate(-1860 -1480)"><g id="Groupe_3" data-name="Groupe 3" transform="translate(0 0)" clip-path="url(#clip-path-picto-hektor-2)"><path id="Trac\xE9_2" data-name="Trac\xE9 2" d="M13.82,1.071Q12.046,0,8.019,0,4.064,0,2.4.961,0,2.289,0,5.8v4.434q0,3.474,2.4,4.8Q4.064,16,8.019,16a11.986,11.986,0,0,0,5.8-1.072Q16,13.635,16,10.235V5.8q0-3.436-2.18-4.73m.964,6.164a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.855,2.889A4.707,4.707,0,0,1,8,8.985a4.707,4.707,0,0,1-2.929,1.139A3.75,3.75,0,0,1,1.216,7.235a.059.059,0,0,1,.107-.049,2.291,2.291,0,0,0,2.022.957A7.284,7.284,0,0,0,6.45,6.8a.548.548,0,0,1,.46-.072L8,7.051l1.09-.319a.548.548,0,0,1,.46.072,7.283,7.283,0,0,0,3.105,1.34,2.292,2.292,0,0,0,2.022-.957.059.059,0,0,1,.106.049" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="#525254"></path></g></g></g></svg>
```